# CUPS printers managing script

Tags: linux, bash, automation, cups

We are using raspberry pi (Raspbian 8) computers as a print servers.
To one raspberry can be connected up to four USB printers (zebra thermal printers).
Printers can be unplugged/switched off/exchanged with other ones.

I need to create a bash script which will monitor connected printers and make a right mappings in CUPS - for example if printer was connected previously as a Zebra2 then it must always be Zebra2 even if it is now the only one printer connected.

I'm thinking about saving printers' serial numbers in file and use it in script for permanent mappings.

I can find connected printers with command:
lpinfo -v

DeviceURI has the following look:
usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%40SSS747?serial=22Y222222222

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using internal Zebranet print servers and ethernet connectivity?

Comment: there are some reasons, yes - we are planning to use other printers also and need some general solution for all types of printers.

also big part of printers used with wifi, not ethernet.